# "starting container failed: su…" in docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-container

currently i am working in docker swarm,
I have made 2 node cluster with docker swarm on bare metal servers.
i have tried to run individual container in each nodes, and they are running. but when i write docker-compose.yml file to run replicas. it gives errors, my **docker-compose.yml** is here.

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: brainplow/shopnroar:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet


  web-dhaar:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: brainplow/dhaar:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - webnet


  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /home/docker/data:/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

and when i run `docker service ls` it gives following,

```
ID                  NAME                       MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                             PORTS
h6irzq0swdat        getstartedlab_redis        replicated          0/1                 redis:latest                      *:6379->6379/tcp
tuchpcxd159x        getstartedlab_visualizer   replicated          0/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:stable   *:8010->8080/tcp
mt5jxxfty0om        getstartedlab_web          replicated          0/2                 brainplow/shopnroar:latest        *:8000->8080/tcp
igz1ceqtawkk        getstartedlab_web-dhaar    replicated          0/2                 brainplow/dhaar:latest            *:9090->9090/tcp
hdya9obuk7ok        redis                      replicated          0/5                 myservice:latest
```

and when i run docker service ps igz1ceqtawkk

it gives me this error,

```
zg7ostkj1ycn         \_ redis.4         myservice:latest    Masternode          Shutdown            Rejected 4 minutes ago        "No such image: myservice:late…"   
xxscungxgmbv         \_ redis.4         myservice:latest    Slavenode           Shutdown            Rejected 4 minutes ago        "No such image: myservice:late…"   
6i5qq5msn6ig        redis.5             myservice:latest    Masternode          Ready               Rejected 2 seconds ago        "No such image: myservice:late…"   
zsvxwm9nsjj6         \_ redis.5         myservice:latest    Masternode          Shutdown            Rejected 32 seconds ago       "No such image: myservice:late…"   
yshbkh62eb7x         \_ redis.5         myservice:latest    Slavenode           Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "No such image: myservice:late…"   
zat104nz0evk         \_ redis.5         myservice:latest    Slavenode           Shutdown            Rejected 3 minutes ago        "No such image: myservice:late…"   
zd4rcb9eeqbb         \_ redis.5         myservice:latest    Slavenode           Shutdown            Rejected 3 minutes ago        "No such image: myservice:late…"
```

and sometime this

```
zy72uf810mka         \_ getstartedlab_web.5   brainplow/shopnroar:latest   Masternode          Shutdown            Failed 21 minutes ago      "starting container failed: su…"   
zzpe0lwoe7cd         \_ getstartedlab_web.5   brainplow/shopnroar:latest   Masternode          Shutdown            Failed 30 minutes ago      "starting container failed: su…"   
zt3eu0jb2uou         \_ getstartedlab_web.5   brainplow/shopnroar:latest   Slavenode           Shutdown            Failed 41 minutes ago      "starting container failed: su…"   
zxesxvq2vumv         \_ getstartedlab_web.5   brainplow/shopnroar:latest   Masternode          Shutdown            Failed 2 hours ago         "starting container failed: su…"
```

can anybody tell me why it is happening.

here is my `docker info`

```
Containers: 2430
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2430
Images: 5
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: wf9o88zy9w4xek011esw9oaa5
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: at6z6315v8d8zs43u1u3dqqca
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 158.69.23.109
 Manager Addresses:
  158.69.23.109:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.33-mod-std-ipv6-64
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.04GiB
Name: Masternode
ID: 3GY6:RP6D:W3SU:FAJV:ZOJP:THFX:TYDF:UZKB:3FJN:WJKC:I23H:MBHO
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: brainplow
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

and

```
docker node ls

ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
wf9o88zy9w4xek011esw9oaa5 *   Masternode          Ready               Active              Leader
n3n38nos3kzcq4g4gl8l0s48c     Slavenode           Ready               Active
```

can anybody tell me why my containers are not running in service. i have stuck on it.

and my `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Thanks in advance. Really needed help on this.

Comment: Docker service ps --no-trunc is usefull to get the full message

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved now. it was due to kernal version. i was working on bare metal cloud and i installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. but i forgot to install kernal that was come with this version.

after reinstalling the Ubuntu with its own kernal, problem was solved.